# How do I fetch only HotelDetails from given json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to display only HotelDetails in table but I got first three row undefined and then in fourth row it display data.

I have done following

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'http://localhost/priya/hotel/gethotelinfo.php',
         dataType: "JSON",
          data: {'HotelCode': HotelCode ,'HotelResultIndex': HotelResultIndex},
           success: function (data) {
                    $obj = JSON.parse(data.Get_Hotel_Info_ResultResult, true);
                    //console.log($obj.HotelInfoResult.HotelDetails);
                   $.each($obj.HotelInfoResult, function (i,obj) {      
                        console.log(obj);               
                    $("#hotel").append("<tr><td>" + obj.HotelCode + "</td><td>" + obj.HotelName + "</td><td>" + obj.StarRating + "</td><td>" + obj.HotelURL + "</td><td>" + obj.Description + "</td><td>" + obj.Address + "</td><td>" + obj.CountryName + "</td><td>" + obj.PinCode + "</td><td>" + obj.HotelContactNo + "</td><td>" + obj.FaxNumber + "</td><td>" + obj.Email + "</td><td>" + obj.Latitude + "</td><td>" + obj.Longitude + "</td><td>" + obj.RoomData + "</td><td>" + obj.RoomFacilities + "</td><td>" + obj.Services + "</td><td><a href='roominfo.php?HotelCode="+obj.HotelCode+"&HotelResultIndex="+obj.ResultIndex+"' target='_blank'>Room</a></td></tr>");
               });
           }
        });
```

This is my json data

```
{"Get_Hotel_Info_ResultResult":"{\"HotelInfoResult\":{\"ResponseStatus\":1,\"Error\":{\"ErrorCode\":0,\"ErrorMessage\":\"\"},\"TraceId\":\"9ca22322-09ed-4ce3-b68d-78a029100f3c\",\"HotelDetails\":{\"HotelCode\":\"1467842\",\"HotelName\":\"The Byke Suraj Plaza\",\"StarRating\":3,\"HotelURL\":null,\"Description\":\"Property Location With a stay at The Byke Suraj Plaza in Thane, you'll be within a 15-minute drive of Sanjay Gandhi National Park and Ovalekar Wadi Butterfly Park.  This hotel is 13.6 mi (21.8 km) from Powai Lake and 15.2 mi (24.5 km) from Kanheri Caves.Rooms Make yourself at home in one of the 122 air-conditioned rooms featuring minibars and flat-screen televisions. Wireless Internet access (surcharge) keeps you connected, and satellite programming is available for your entertainment. Bathrooms have showers and complimentary toiletries. Conveniences include laptop-compatible safes and desks, and housekeeping is provided daily.Amenities Take in the views from a rooftop terrace and make use of amenities such as wireless Internet access (surcharge) and concierge services. Guests can catch a ride to nearby destinations on the area shuttle (surcharge).Dining Enjoy a meal at Farm Fresh or snacks in the coffee shop\\\/café. The hotel also offers 24-hour room service. Quench your thirst with your favorite drink at the bar\\\/lounge. Breakfast is available for a fee.Business, Other Amenities Featured amenities include a business center, express check-in, and complimentary newspapers in the lobby. A roundtrip airport shuttle is provided for a surcharge (available 24 hours), and free valet parking is available onsite.&nbsp;<br\\\/><b>Disclaimer notification: Amenities are subject to availability and may be chargeable as per the hotel policy.<\\\/b>&nbsp; <br \\\/>\",\"Attractions\":[{\"Key\":\"1) \",\"Value\":\"Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer. <br \\\/> <p>Ovalekar Wadi Butterfly Park - 2 km \\\/ 1.3 mi <br \\\/> Sanjay Gandhi National Park - 2.2 km \\\/ 1.3 mi <br \\\/> Tikuji-ni-Wadi - 4 km \\\/ 2.5 mi <br \\\/> Jupiter Hospital - 6.8 km \\\/ 4.2 mi <br \\\/> Viviana Mall - 6.9 km \\\/ 4.3 mi <br \\\/> Masunda Lake - 8.3 km \\\/ 5.2 mi <br \\\/> Korum Mall - 8.4 km \\\/ 5.2 mi <br \\\/> Nirmal Lifestyle Mall - 14.3 km \\\/ 8.9 mi <br \\\/> Dhirubhai Ambani Life Science Centre - 16.7 km \\\/ 10.4 mi <br \\\/> Reliance Corporate Park - 17.7 km \\\/ 11 mi <br \\\/> Indian Institute of Technology Bombay - 21.1 km \\\/ 13.1 mi <br \\\/> Powai Lake - 21.8 km \\\/ 13.6 mi <br \\\/> Hiranandani Business Park - Powai - 21.9 km \\\/ 13.6 mi <br \\\/> Sagar Vihar Garden - 22.1 km \\\/ 13.7 mi <br \\\/> R City Mall - 22.7 km \\\/ 14.1 mi <br \\\/> <\\\/p><p>The nearest major airport is Mumbai (BOM-Chhatrapati Shivaji Intl.) - 31.3 km \\\/ 19.4 mi<\\\/p>\"}],\"HotelFacilities\":[\"24-hour front desk\",\" Accessible bathroom\",\" Airport transportation (surcharge)\",\" Area shuttle (surcharge)\",\" Bar\\\/lounge\",\" Breakfast available (surcharge)\",\" Business center\",\" Coffee shop or café\",\" Concierge services\",\" Dry cleaning\\\/laundry service\",\" Express check-in\",\" Free newspapers in lobby\",\" Free self parking\",\" Free valet parking\",\" Hair salon\",\" In-room accessibility\",\" Laundry facilities\",\" Luggage storage\",\" One meeting room\",\" Restaurant\",\" Roll-in shower\",\" Rooftop terrace\",\" Safe-deposit box at front desk\",\" Smoke-free property\",\" Total number of rooms - 122\",\" Tours\\\/ticket assistance\",\" WiFi (surcharge)\"],\"HotelPolicy\":\"Early check out will attract full cancellation charge unless otherwise specified.|Infant 2 year(s) : Stay for free if using existing bedding. Note, if you need a cot there may be an extra charge.Children 3 - 8 year(s)||\",\"SpecialInstructions\":null,\"HotelPicture\":null,\"Images\":[\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViQft3Fw1qpmR6kk3e3k6P7Q==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViZjgsA99WkKrt92k4Iwg9BA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViQSco4b\\\/CO8tbKvng9OWBxQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVi6wbMBCeXE3FRBCfR6N4jSQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViqBrWYSdg4QxOqGHhjB+7jg==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViiK46a16e7Hx7xHz995J1hQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVif0NiR1vUaLR7Z6uVm15lUA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVicyi0wl9sMTlluzDNPQCFOA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViwEvK8uPBXP5Cfa0kNCbxuQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVif2l7x4lymRrkt7UYdxOd5g==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVirhtOCDApkOSsvPId6i\\\/CeQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVi7RTOw2OascdIckeVcnu7fg==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVigvBX7hR4G3YJ5KUqsUZLfw==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViHmQB4WZOUbzp+kIadTMfwA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViZR+EIkgo6qTy2Or\\\/eCWLeQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBlUnar3TsLeBV97vs454NMyLpnK3AGwA+g==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViO6glJ56m\\\/38RH5nsTle1aA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVi+U2wtqYiHubMYtlNLs6rJw==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViNBkRD2AkODc2lefNbuPOKQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMVie+siDTtE3wFQGCJ3i4zQGQ==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViFjxtMAjV5p0JmFBc5LAoDA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViAfP1Rf1wjLPOFIzD16wMVA==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViLj0+jfW3knW6Bxpm51YFCg==\",\"https:\\\/\\\/api.tbotechnology.in\\\/imageresource.aspx?img=FbrGPTrju5e5v0qrAGTD8pPBsj8\\\/wYA5lPqBj\\\/Ape0\\\/QCIe+Q6uhRW8BLHBV4q8CAf9tiXj7YvBe+TX5\\\/JRvBqLUX4ibZMViYRI7NIu061rgbfUYomXDfQ==\"],\"Address\":\"Ghodbunder Road, Saibaba Vihar Complex, Thane, 400615, India, India\",\"CountryName\":\"India\",\"PinCode\":\"400615\",\"HotelContactNo\":\"+912225971111\",\"FaxNumber\":null,\"Email\":null,\"Latitude\":\"19.26288\",\"Longitude\":\"72.96841\",\"RoomData\":null,\"RoomFacilities\":null,\"Services\":null}}}"}
```

I want to display HotelsDetails in table curretly i am getting first three row undefined

Comment: Start with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, please.

Comment: What happens if you try to parse that data?

Comment: _“I want to display HotelsDetails in table curretly i am getting first three row undefined”_ - that’s probably because you are not looping over `$obj.HotelInfoResult.HotelDetails`, but `$obj.HotelInfoResult` instead.

Comment: If I do so I got error , "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HotelDetails' of undefined" @04FS

Comment: Even then `HotelDetails` is a single object, so there's nothing to actually loop through, so just remove the loop: https://jsfiddle.net/tf8vs0do/

Comment: can you change your json data returning from ajax call?

Comment: You don’t have a really deeply nested data structure here, all you got is one single property named `Get_Hotel_Info_ResultResult` that contains all the rest as a string value - you would need to decode that string value again to get a proper nested data structure for the rest to begin with. But this should probably rather be fixed in the place where this JSON is generated in the first place …

Answer (score 0):

why you are using $obj, simply create one var variable and check if it works or not.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.Get_Hotel_Info_ResultResult, true);
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the problem

Comment: It's all in the question itself, and the comments underneath